# ArrayIterator's key() doesn't work in for loop?

Tags: php

Does anyone can explain to me, why does `key()` doesn't work in `for` loop properly?

**Example**

```
$iterator = new \ArrayIterator(range(1,3));
for ($iterator->seek(0); $iterator->key() < 3; $iterator->next()) {
    echo "{$iterator->key()} => {$iterator->current()}", PHP_EOL;
}
```

It return infinity loop, but if I change second expression of `for` loop on:
`$iterator->key() < 2`
It doesn't display last element. Can anyone explain why?

I need to display 2 elements, change pointer in array on X, then display 3 elements, change pointer in array on Y, then display 2 elements... etc.

Comment: The problem is that after your last element with the key 2 you will move to the next element with `next()` and you don't have one after that. So getting the key from an element which doesn't exist with `key()` will return NULL. In the numeric context with `key < 3` the key, means NULL, will be converted to an integer. So NULL will be 0 and 0 is smaller than 3. That causes the infinite loop. Use `$iterator->valid()` in your condition part of the for loop to always make sure you have a valid element.

Comment: To piggyback on what @Rizier123 said. Something like this `    if($iterator->valid())
    {
        echo "{$iterator->key()} => {$iterator->current()}", PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        die(0); // or whatever
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `foreach`

```
foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    // Do the things you gotta do here...
}
```

I guess you aren't asking for a solution, you just want to know why. As others have explained, once the iterator gets to the last element `$iterator->key()` is `null` which is `< 3` and will remain that way.